# SOLVED - Select2 attr "selected" stop working when set false

Tags: jquery-select2

The goal is to select users according to the option chosen in the first select.
It works fine the first time you select that type of user. But when I change the user type and go back to the previous one, it doesn't show the options in the select. But through the inspect element it appears that the option has the "selected" attribute

```
<label for="UserType" class="col-md-2 control-label">User Type nbsp;<span class="text-danger small">*</span></label> <div class="col-md-4">
<select class="select2_demo_1 form-control" id="UserType" name="UserType">
    <option value='0' selected disabled hidden>-- Selecionar --</option>
    <option value="1">Boss</option>
    <option value="2">Admin</option>
    <option value="3">User</option>
</select>
```

```
<label for="Users" class="col-md-2 control-label">Users&nbsp;<span class="text-danger small">*</span></label><div class="col-md-10">
<select id="Users" name="Users" class="select2_demo_1 form-control" multiple  style="width:100%">
    <option data-type='1' value="1" >User Boss</option>
    <option data-type='2' value="2" >User Admin</option>
    <option data-type='2' value="3" >User Admin 2</option>
    <option data-type='3' value="4" >User</option>
</select>
```

```
$('#UserType').on('change', function() {
    var UserType = $(this).val();
    $("select#Users option:selected").attr("selected",false); 
    $("select#Users option[data-type="+ UserType +"]").attr("selected","selected");
    $("#Users").select2();  
});
$('#UserType').trigger('change');
```

------ Solution ------

Change the code segment

```
$("select#Users option:selected").attr("selected",false); 
    $("select#Users option[data-type="+ UserType +"]").attr("selected","selected");
    $("#Users").select2();
```

by the following

```
$('#UserType').select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', false).end().select2();
$('#UserType').select2('destroy').find('option[data-type='+ UserType+']').prop('selected', 'selected').end().select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may think to add `selected="true"` and then change it to `false` when you apply the function `attr()`